# Pass id value from ahref to bootstrap modal php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php code that creates a list from the database. One of the items I retrieve from the database is the row id.  I create the list in the following code:

```
    <th>Cover Name</th>
      <th>Sum Insured</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th style="width: 3.5em;"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_set)) { ?>
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo $row['cover_name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo 'R '.$row['sum_insured'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['info'] ?></td>
      <td>
          <a href="cover-type.php?id=<?php echo $row['coverid']?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
         <a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

The syntax for calling `#myModal`

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

as you can see the anchor `#myModal` and `onclick`

After clicking anchor I would like to pass `$coverid` to the following myModal pop up

```
    <div class="modal small fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="error-text"><i class="fa fa-warning modal-icon"></i>Are you sure you want to delete the cover?<br>This cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <a href="delete-cover.php?id=<?php echo $coverid ?>" class="btn btn-danger"  >Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I under the impression that I need to have some form a hidden javascript variable in

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a> and pass it to myModal window, but how do I do that ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. uses a single modal
2. use attribute data-id to store cover id: `data-id="< ?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>"`
3. add class to trash icon, for example `class="trash"`
4. add id for Delete button in modal, for example `id="modalDelete"`

and in JQ:

```
// on clik trash icon    
$('.trash').click(function(){
    //get cover id
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    //set href for cancel button
    $('#modallCancel').attr('href','delete-cover.php?id='+id);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4j59z60e/4/

Comment: Firstly, I'm not copied your answer. Secondly, I responded exactly as it is supposed to set the href and not the value of the input field. Third, I have set an example on JSFIDDLE and explain the important parts of the code. Therefore, it accepted my answer. On this site I have a lot of answers so that it should be to show that I have some knowledge. It happened to me a similar situation but I'm not complaining. And finally you have the right to have your opinion, regardless of whether you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#myModal" class="trash" data-id="<?php echo $row['coverid']; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

In your modal, you will get the id like this (for example):

```
<input id="feed_id" value="" />
```

Add:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.trash',function(){
        document.getElementById("feed_id").value = $(this).attr('data-id');
            console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });
    });
}
```

https://torbjornzetterlund.com/passing-data-list-bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score -1):

PHP is executed on server while JavaScript is executed on client. This code

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">...</a>
```

will actually transform into

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="" role="button" data-toggle="modal">...</a>
```

because the PHP part didn't echo anything.

So, you'll rather have to so something like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="show_dialog('<?php echo $row['coverid']; ?>')" role="button" data-toggle="modal">...</a>
```

Assuming you have PHP variable `$row` defined and `$row['coverid']` is, say, 1337, then this HTML will be rendered to browser:

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="show_dialog(1337)" role="button" data-toggle="modal">...</a>
```

thus, if you define JavaScript function `show_dialog`, it will get called with value from `$row['coverid']`. The only way to pass variables from PHP to JavaScript is to echo their values from PHP in the place where you have JavaScript code.

A good practice for this is to use a `<script>` block somewhere on the top of your page with following content:

```
window.php_vars = window.php_vars || {};
window.php_vars.some_value = '<?php echo $some_value; ?>';
window.php_vars.some_other_value = '<?php echo $some_other_value; ?>';
window.php_vars.foo = '<?php echo 'bar'; ?>';
```

...but this approach works only for scalar types (ints, strings etc).

Comment: Thanks, I understand it a bit better now. Now what will put inside this line  <a href="delete-cover.php?id=<?php echo $coverid ?>" class="btn btn-danger"  >Delete</a> ?

Comment: @kya I updated the response and added 4th code part.

Comment: onclick="show_dialog('<?php echo $row['coverid']; ?>')"
This will not work !

Comment: @xe4me can you explain why?

Comment: @AndrewDunai Now, we need to pass the id of 1337 into the Modal. How do we do that using onclick="show_dialog" ?

Comment: @xe4me can you please explain ?

Comment: There are  three nested quote in that line , it will not work like that , please check and edit it

Comment: @AndrewDunai, i think the question I should be asking is, how do take the value 1337 from the onclick="show_dialog" and store in a php variable $coverid ?

Comment: How is assigning variables to window object , is a "good practice" ?
Are you kidding ?

Comment: @mongoer How is even using PHP with echoes or Mongo a good practice?

Comment: @AndrewDunai , brother , you have 2 errors in your sentence , dont be mad at me , First of all , it is not good practice to put javascript files at the top of your page , And Second , it is not good practice to use window object like this , why ? because if you simple use "use strict" in your javascript , you wot be able to assign variables to window . and there are lots of other issues you can search

Comment: @AndrewDunai , how this problem is related to Mongo , are you high or something ?